# Pandas get minimum total in moving window

Tags: python, pandas

I have something like the following dataframe:

```
df=pd.Series(index=pd.date_range(start='1/1/2017', end='1/10/2017', freq='D'),
             data=[5,5,2,1,3,4,5,6,7,8])

df
Out[216]: 
2017-01-01    5
2017-01-02    5
2017-01-03    2
2017-01-04    1
2017-01-05    3
2017-01-06    4
2017-01-07    5
2017-01-08    6
2017-01-09    7
2017-01-10    8
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

I want to identify the start date of the 3 day period that has the minimum total value. So in this example, 2017-01-03 through 2017-01-05, has the minimum value with a sum of 6 across those 3 days.

Is there a way to do this without looping through each 3 day window?

The result would be:

```
2017-01-03    6
```

And if there were multiple windows that have the same minimum sum, the result could have a record for each.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IIUC    `rolling`

```
df=pd.Series(index=pd.date_range(start='1/1/2017', end='1/10/2017', freq='D'),
             data=[5,5,2,1,3,4,5,6,7,8])
df=df.to_frame()
df['New']=df.rolling(3).sum().shift(-2).values
df.loc[df.New==df.New.min(),:].drop(0,1)

Out[685]: 
            New
2017-01-03  6.0
```

Comment: this is great. And to clarify if I wanted to change the window size to 4 (as an example) it would be df['New']=df.rolling(4).sum().shift(-3).values. Is that correct?

Comment: @AJG519 yes , you got it